# Method was used outside of a Grails Application

Tags: hibernate, grails, groovy

When I go to use the save action on my domain class, I get a flash message with the following error:

```
Method on class [com.xxxxxxx.Detail] was used outside of a Grails application.
 If running in the context of a test using the mocking API or bootstrap Grails correctly.
```

Running Grails 2.3.7 and Hibernate should be updated just fine.
My bootstrap is working just fine, and I am able to save domain class instances in it. But when i try to save a Detail class instance from the development environment, I get this error.

Why am I getting this error? Any ideas?

Thanks!

BuildConfig.groovy contains:

```
dependencies {
        build "com.google.gwt:gwt:2.5.1"
        compile 'org.ccil.cowan.tagsoup:tagsoup:1.2'
        compile "org.apache.solr:solr-solrj:4.6.1"
        compile "commons-dbcp:commons-dbcp:1.4"
        runtime  'org.postgresql:postgresql:9.3-1100-jdbc41'
        compile "ar.com.fdvs:DynamicJasper:5.0.0"

    }

    plugins {
        // Java 6.0 has this already
        runtime(':mail:1.0') { excludes 'mail', 'activiation', 'spring-test' }

        runtime ":hibernate:3.6.10.10"
        build ":tomcat:7.0.52.1"
        compile ":smartgwt:0.2"
        build ":extended-dependency-manager:0.5.5"
        compile ":gwt:1.0", {
            transitive=false

        }
        compile ":cxf:1.1.1"

        compile ":executor:0.3"
        compile ":grails-melody:1.48.0"
        runtime ":jquery:1.10.2.2"
        compile ":modalbox:0.4"
        compile ":ofchart:0.6.3"
        compile ":quartz:1.0.1"
        compile ":remote-pagination:0.4.6"
        compile ":richui:0.8"
        compile ":spring-security-core:2.0-RC2"
        compile ":android-gcm:0.2"
        compile ":aws-sdk:1.6.12"
        runtime ":resources:1.2.7"
        compile ":csv:0.3.1"
        compile ":jasper:1.7.0"
        compile ":dynamic-jasper:0.6"
        compile ":postgresql-extensions:0.6.1"
        compile ":modalbox:0.4"
        compile ":jquery-ui:1.10.3"
    }
```

Error

```
2014/03/07 00:20:22 [thread:63] INFO  Date  - Thu Mar 06 00:00:00 UTC 2014
    | Error java.lang.IllegalStateException: Method on class [com.xxxxxxxx.Detail] was used outside of a Grails application. If running in the context of a test using the mocking API or bootstrap Grails correctly.
    | Error     at com.xxxxxxxx.Detail.currentGormValidationApi(Detail.groovy)
    | Error     at com.xxxxxxxx.Detail.validate(Detail.groovy)
    | Error     at com.xxxxxxxx.Detail$validate$2.call(Unknown Source)
    | Error     at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:45)
    | Error     at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:108)
    | Error     at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:112)
    | Error     at com.apporder.Report$__clinit__closure19_closure21_closure22.doCall(Report.groovy:49)
    | Error     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    | Error     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    | Error     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    | Error     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    | Error     at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
    | Error     at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:233)
    | Error     at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1086)
    | Error     at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1110)
    | Error     at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:910)
    | Error     at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:411)
    | Error     at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:427)
    | Error     at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.DefaultGroovyMethods.each(DefaultGroovyMethods.java:1325)
    | Error     at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.DefaultGroovyMethods.each(DefaultGroovyMethods.java:1297)
    | Error     at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.dgm$148.invoke(Unknown Source)
    | Error     at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PojoMetaMethodSite$PojoMetaMethodSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.invoke(PojoMetaMethodSite.java:271)
    | Error     at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PojoMetaMethodSite.call(PojoMetaMethodSite.java:53)
    | Error     at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:45)
    | Error     at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:108)
    | Error     at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:116)
    | Error     at com.apporder.Report$__clinit__closure19_closure21.doCall(Report.groovy:47)
    | Error     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    | Error     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    | Error     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    | Error     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    | Error     at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
    | Error     at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:233)
    | Error     at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1086)
    | Error     at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1110)
    | Error     at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:910)
    | Error     at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:411)
    | Error     at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.validation.ValidatorConstraint.processValidate(ValidatorConstraint.java:85)
    | Error     at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.validation.AbstractConstraint.validate(AbstractConstraint.java:107)
    | Error     at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.validation.ConstrainedProperty.validate(ConstrainedProperty.java:960)
    | Error     at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.validation.GrailsDomainClassValidator.validatePropertyWithConstraint(GrailsDomainClassValidator.java:209)
    | Error     at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.validation.GrailsDomainClassValidator.validate(GrailsDomainClassValidator.java:79)
    | Error     at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate.validation.HibernateDomainClassValidator.validate(HibernateDomainClassValidator.java:66)
    | Error     at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate.metaclass.AbstractSavePersistentMethod.doInvokeInternal(AbstractSavePersistentMethod.java:173)
    | Error     at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate.metaclass.AbstractDynamicPersistentMethod.invoke(AbstractDynamicPersistentMethod.java:63)
    | Error     at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate.HibernateGormInstanceApi.save(HibernateGormInstanceApi.groovy:196)
    | Error     at com.apporder.Report.save(Report.groovy)
    | Error     at com.apporder.Report$save$12.call(Unknown Source)
    | Error     at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:45)
    | Error     at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:108)
    | Error     at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:116)
    | Error     at com.apporder.service.ReportTransactionalService.create(ReportTransactionalService.groovy:718)
    | Error     at com.apporder.service.ReportTransactionalService$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$6fd1cc0d.invoke(<generated>)
    | Error     at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
    | Error     at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:700)
    | Error     at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
    | Error     at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
    | Error     at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:260)
    | Error     at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:94)
    | Error     at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    | Error     at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:633)
    | Error     at com.apporder.service.ReportTransactionalService$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$8c34825d.create(<generated>)
    | Error     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    | Error     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    | Error     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    | Error     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    | Error     at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
    | Error     at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:233)
    | Error     at groovy.lang.MetaMethod$doMethodInvoke.call(Unknown Source)
    | Error     at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:45)
    | Error     at groovy.lang.MetaMethod$doMethodInvoke.call(Unknown Source)
    | Error     at GrailsMelodyGrailsPlugin$_closure4_closure16_closure17.doCall(GrailsMelodyGrailsPlugin.groovy:184)
    | Error     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    | Error     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    | Error     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    | Error     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    | Error     at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
    | Error     at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.ClosureMetaMethod.invoke(ClosureMetaMethod.java:80)
    | Error     at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1108)
    | Error     at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:910)
    | Error     at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.call(PogoMetaClassSite.java:39)
    | Error     at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:45)
    | Error     at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:108)
    | Error     at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:128)
    | Error     at com.apporder.ReportController$_closure15.doCall(ReportController.groovy:325)
    | Error     at com.apporder.ReportController$_closure15.doCall(ReportController.groovy)
    | Error     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    | Error     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    | Error     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    | Error     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    | Error     at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
    | Error     at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:233)
    | Error     at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1086)
    | Error     at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1110)
    | Error     at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:910)
    | Error     at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:411)
    | Error     at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:405)
    | Error     at com.apporder.ReportController.save(ReportController.groovy)
    | Error     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    | Error     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    | Error     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    | Error     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    | Error     at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet.mvc.MixedGrailsControllerHelper.invoke(MixedGrailsControllerHelper.java:154)
    | Error     at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet.mvc.AbstractGrailsControllerHelper.handleAction(AbstractGrailsControllerHelper.java:354)
    | Error     at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet.mvc.AbstractGrailsControllerHelper.executeAction(AbstractGrailsControllerHelper.java:231)
    | Error     at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet.mvc.AbstractGrailsControllerHelper.handleURI(AbstractGrailsControllerHelper.java:197)
    | Error     at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet.mvc.AbstractGrailsControllerHelper.handleURI(AbstractGrailsControllerHelper.java:121)
    | Error     at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleGrailsController.handleRequest(SimpleGrailsController.java:72)
    | Error     at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.handle(SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.java:48)
    | Error     at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet.GrailsDispatcherServlet.doDispatch(GrailsDispatcherServlet.java:355)
    | Error     at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:856)
    | Error     at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:953)
    | Error     at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:855)
    | Error     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:646)
    | Error     at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:829)
    | Error     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    | Error     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    | Error     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    | Error     at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    | Error     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    | Error     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    | Error     at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:101)
    | Error     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    | Error     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    | Error     at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:101)
    | Error     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    | Error     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    | Error     at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:101)
    | Error     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    | Error     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    | Error     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:748)
    | Error     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:486)
    | Error     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:411)
    | Error     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:338)
    | Error     at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.util.WebUtils.forwardRequestForUrlMappingInfo(WebUtils.java:332)
```

Detail.groovy constraints:

```
class Detail {
    static constraints = {
        value(nullable: true, validator: { value, detail ->
            def ret = true
            if (detail.detailType.subType != "calculated") {
                if (detail.detailType.required && Utilities.inList(detail.detailType.type, ["text", "string", "boolean",
                        "number", "numberPunctuation", "phone", "email", "date", "time", "dateTime"]) &&
                        (value == null || value.trim() == ""))
                    ret = "default.selection.required.message"
                else if (detail.detailType.type == "number" && value != null && value.trim() != "" && !value.isNumber())
                    ret = "default.mustbenumeric.message"
                else if (detail.detailType.required && detail.detailType.type == "refersTo" && detail.refersTo == null)
                    ret = "default.selection.required.message"
            }
            //println "validate ${detail.detailType.name} type[${detail.detailType.type}] required[${detail.detailType.required}] value[${value}] refersTo[${detail?.refersTo?.id}]:${ret}"
            return ret
        })
        selection(nullable: true, validator: { selection, detail ->
            def ret = true
            if (detail?.detailType?.subType == "calculated") return true
            if (detail?.detailType?.required && Utilities.inList(detail.detailType.type, ["menu", "selectOne"]) &&
                    selection == null)
                ret = "default.selection.required.message"
            //println "validate ${detail.detailType.name} selection[${selection}]:${ret}"
            return ret
        })
        parent(nullable: true)
        details(nullable: true)
        audioClipId(nullable: true)
        refersTo(nullable: true, validator: { selection, detail ->
            def ret = true
            if (detail.detailType.required && detail.detailType == "refersTo" && detail.refersTo == null) {
                ret = "default.selection.required.message"
            }
            return ret
        })
        sort(nullable: true)
        placeholderReportId(nullable: true)
    }
```

Comment: Add more details about `ReportController`, `Report` and `Detail`.

Comment: They are very large domain classes... (I didn't write them...) What details would you like?

Comment: At least the constraints block of Detail.

Comment: I assume the version is really 2.3.7?

Comment: try like this to find out any validation errors occurs. detailObject.validate()

Comment: I have another doubt. Did you change the buildconfig file. because in garils 2.2.3,  runtime ":hibernate:$grailsVersion",build ":tomcat:$grailsVersion" like that. But yours having compile ":hibernate:3.6.10.9"
        build ":tomcat:7.0.52.1".

Comment: Constraints have been added for Detail. I'm changing my hibernate to runtime and testing it right now. Will report back soon.

Comment: After updating to hibernate 3.6.10.10 and using "runtime" I still get the same error.

Comment: Hi together, same problem here with grails 2.4. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23999078/method-was-used-outside-of-a-grails-application-after-upgrade-to-grails-2-4-0

Comment: Does it still happen if you uninstall the grails-melody plugin?

Answer (score 0):

I have this error few times:

- when datasource was initatiate in a wrong [convention](http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/2.2.1/guide/conf.html#multipleDatasources) (f.e. you should use in Datasource.groovy **dataSource_example** (watch out for big letter and underscore), and use

  ```
  static mapping = {
      datasource 'example'
  }
  ```

it's quite easy to diagnose: check if tables in database are properly initiated

- when file with external config wasn't loaded (because of lack of privillages). it's connected with previous example, because I stored there my dev datasource config